# load taxonomy content based on other taxonomy term in drupal

Tags: drupal, taxonomy, drupal-content-types

I have created a taxonomy term "Country" and another one "City" and added both in my custom content type as term reference, I want to filter "City" field content based on the selection of "Country" term while adding that particular content. How to achieve it, any clue.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know the version of drupal you are using, but it sounds like the [conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module can help you.

There are a few gotchas though when using it with term reference fields - [this](http://www.webbykat.com/2013/04/conditional-fields-and-term-reference-tree-two-small-bugs-their-resolution) should help.